# DB migration before Lambda deployment with Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to figure out the best workflow for executing DB migration before a lambda function gets deployed (or comes online)
My setup is as follows:

1. SAM template to define my function
2. The function is a django app

- DB migration can be run by calling `management.call_command(command_name="migrate", noinput=True)` from python code

3. Terraform config files to define roles and CloudFormation stack for the lambda

Lambda building and packaging is done with `SAM CLI`, and deployment is triggered by `terraform apply`

One approach I considered is adding `DeploymentPreference` section in SAM template, and running migration from a `PreTraffic` hook function, but not too sure that's the best approach.

What other options are there to run db migration scripts before Lambda deployment ?